# p:dataTable selected value setter doesn't work

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm new in JSF and PrimeFaces and I can't understand why my setter for selected value doesn't set:

I've got main XHTML in which after click on `<p:commandButton>` I want to change selected row. But after changing selection of the row on data setter `setSelectedBook()` get `null` value on entrance.

I already set `selection` and `rowKey` for `<p:dataTable>`.

It looks like :

main XTML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      >

    <body>
        <ui:composition template="./../../WEB-INF/pagesTemplate.xhtml">
            <form>
                <ui:define name="content">

                    <p:dataTable id="eventsDT" var="book" value="#{bookHolder.books}"
                                 selectionMode= "single" selection="#{bookController.selectedBook}"
                                 rowKey="#{book.id}">

                        <p:ajax event="rowSelect"/>
                        <p:ajax event="rowDblselect" listener="#{bookController.onDoubleRowSelect}"  />

                        <p:column headerText="ID">
                            <h:outputText value="#{book.id}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Title">
                            <h:outputText value="#{book.longName}" />
                        </p:column>

                    </p:dataTable>
                </ui:define>

                <ui:define name="right">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="5">
                        <p:commandButton id="btnEdit" value="Edit"
                                         action="#{navigationController.moveToBookEditPageSimple}"
                                         style="width: 100px;height: 28px; margin-left: 10%"/>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </ui:define>

            </form>
        </ui:composition>
    </body>
</html>
```

BookController that can't get value:

```
@Named("bookController")
@SessionScoped
@Local(BookView.class)
public class BookController implements Serializable {

    public BookController() {
        navigator = new NavigationController();
    }

    NavigationController navigator;

    @Inject
    BookHolder bookHolder;

    private Book selectedBook;

    public Book getSelectedBook() {
        return selectedBook;
    }

    public void setSelectedBook(Book selectedBookValue) {
        this.selectedBook = selectedBookValue;
    }

    public void onDoubleRowSelect(SelectEvent event) throws IOException {
        String str = navigator.showPage("BookEdit");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(str + ".xhtml");
    }      
}
```

BookHolderBean that contains data:

```
@Named("bookHolder")
@ApplicationScoped
public class BookHolder {

    public BookHolder() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    void setValues() {
        this.books = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            this.books.add(new Book(new ParkType(i, i,
                    "Book #: " + i + " (long name)",
                    "Book #: " + i + " (short name)",
                    "Book #: " + i + " (note)")));

        }
    }

    private List<Book> books;

    public List<Book> getBooks() {
        return books;
    }

    public void setBooks(List<Book> parkTypes) {
        this.books = parkTypes;
    }
}
```

Class Book:

```
public class Book extends MainEntitie<Book> implements Serializable, SelectableDataModel<Book> {
    @Inject
    BookHolder bookHolder;

    private final String longName;
    private final String shortName;

    public Book(BookBase sd) {
        super(sd.getId(), false, false, sd.getNote());
        this.longName = sd.getLongName();
        this.shortName = sd.getShortName();
    }

    public String getLongName() {
        return longName;
    }

    public String getShortName() {
        return shortName;
    }

    @Override
    public int getId() {
        return super.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getRowKey(Book t) {
        return t.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public Book getRowData(String string) {
        for (Book app : bookHolder.getBooks()) {
            if (app.getId() == Integer.parseInt(string)) {
                return app;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Quite confusing things. Why don't you just use `LazyDataModel<T>`? It is a kind of specialization of `SelectableDataModel<T>`. Why don't you just extend your managed bean class (`BookHolder`) using `LazyDataModel<T>` and make use of its one of the overloaded versions of `public List<T> load(...)`?

Comment: Because I only try to understand how does jsf works after programming on .net and didn't know about LazyDataModel. Thank you for your advise, I'll read information about this and try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use `ui:define`, I assume there is a `ui:include` in your template file (`pagesTemplate.xhtml`). 
If so, that is great, but your included page has some unnecessary stuff, e.g. html and body tag (by the way: use [`h:body`](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_body.html)). No need for that.

See [second part of this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4793959/2627644) to learn how to include an xhtml file into another one.

You will notice that the content of `ui:define` is kind of "cut&pasted" into the your template file.
So, what about your `form` tag? It's being ignored (at least, I guess it won't be a parent of your datatable).
Make the `h:form` (again, use JSF's `h:form` instead of HTML `form`) a child of `ui:define`,
like:

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/template.xhtml"
xmlns=.....>
   <ui:define name="content">
      <h:form>
         <p:dataTable ...>
            ...
         </p:dataTable>
      </h:form>
   </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: Thank you very much - It works! I removed from main xhtml tags <form> and <body> and paste <h: form> around datatable and setter started to work.

Comment: A plain body (not an h:body) outside of a composition is fine... even an head and html is fine, heck, everything **outside** composition  is fine (according to the jsf spec) e.g. see http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-templating-with-facelets-example/ One reason to use html/head/body outside a composition is that IDE's sometimes better recognise the files for designing things